# Kendoui windows ist not scrolling in a kendo.layout

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to display a long kendoui window in a Kendoui layout. 
The window doesnt scroll along with the page, it stays at the same place at all times.

If I deactivate the Kendo.layout, it scrolls fine.

Any ideas?

Mike

Comment: This is called [pinning](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#configuration-pinned). It is  off by default but seems like you are TRUEing it on window configuration.

Comment: Please post a sample of your case.